# Get first date of month in postgres

Tags: postgresql, date, triggers

I'm trying to get a 'date' type that corresponds to the first day of the current month.  Basically one of my tables stores a date, but I want it to always be the first of the month, so I'm trying to create a trigger that will get now() and then replace the day with a 1.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You can use the expression `date_trunc('month', current_date)`. Demonstrated with a SELECT statement . . .

```
select date_trunc('month', current_date)
2013-08-01 00:00:00-04
```

To remove time, cast to date.

```
select cast(date_trunc('month', current_date) as date)
2013-08-01
```

If you're certain that column should *always* store only the first of a month, you should also use a CHECK constraint.

```
create table foo (
  first_of_month date not null
  check (extract (day from first_of_month) = 1)
);

insert into foo (first_of_month) values ('2015-01-01'); --Succeeds
insert into foo (first_of_month) values ('2015-01-02'); --Fails
```

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "foo" violates check constraint "foo_first_of_month_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2015-01-02).
```

Comment: I used to do it like this select cast((now() - (extract(day from now())) * interval '1 day') + interval '1 day' as date) as first_of_month but this helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

`date_trunc()` will do it.

```
SELECT date_trunc('MONTH',now())::DATE;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 10):

You can also use TO_CHAR to get the first day of the month:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(some_date, 'yyyy-mm-01')::date
```

Answer (score 6):

Found this to get the first day of that month and the last date of that month

```
select date_trunc('month', current_date-interval '1 year'), date_trunc('month', current_date-interval '1 year')+'1month'::interval-'1day'::interval;
```

Comment: Why ```-interval '1 year'```?

Comment: That is for getting previous year, first and last day of a month based on the current time.
It can be removed to get the current year like select date_trunc('month', current_date-interval '1 year'), date_trunc('month', current_date)+'1month'::interval-'1day'::interval;

Answer (score 2):

SELECT TO_DATE('2017-12-12', 'YYYY-MM-01');

> 2017-12-01

Comment: What is the problem with this answer?

Comment: probably just that you used a static data rather than the CURRENT_DATE()?

Comment: that is the problem:
LINE 1: SELECT TO_DATE("t1"."date", 'YYYY-MM-01') AS ddate, Sum("t1"...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: You should use to_char instead e.g. SELECT TO_CHAR('2017-12-12', 'YYYY-MM-01')::date

Answer (score 0):

date_trunc() always returns the first day of provided type.

for example

```
SELECT date_trunc('MONTH',now())::DATE will return the first day of month;

SELECT date_trunc('YEAR',now())::DATE will return the first day of year;

SELECT date_trunc('CENTURY',now())::DATE will return the first day of century;
```

::DATE changes the format of returned data to date format YYYY-MM-DD