# SQL Query for all purchases in a given month

Tags: sql

I'm going through a SQL tutorial, and came across this question.
I've been stuck for sometime.

**Customers**

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY    
lastname VARCHAR    
firstname VARCHAR
```

**Purchases**

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY    
customers_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY customers(id)    
purchasedate DATETIME    
purchaseamount REAL
```

`Write a statement that gives a list of all customers who purchases something this month.`

I know I want to inner-join the tables on customer_id and then get the customer names where the month is February, does this look right?

```
SELECT * from Purchases
    inner join Customers
    on Purchases.customers_id=Customers.id
WHERE MONTH(purchasedate) = 2
```

Comment: You need to consider that every year has a second month.

Comment: Note quite.  This will repeat customers.  You need to only show distinct customers.id.

Comment: you have your `purchasedate` listed as an integer, assuming that's a typo and should be `datetime`

Comment: @Kritner you are correct, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, or to avoid the whole `distinct` business you could write

```
SELECT id, LastName, firstname FROM Customers
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Purchases 
               WHERE customers_id=Customers.id
               AND MONTH(purchasedate)=2 AND YEAR(purchasedate)=2016 )
```

Comment: Worthy of note that you recognize the importance of year.

Answer (score 2):

I will go with `EXISTS` which will avoid duplicate

```
SELECT Customers.id,
       Customers.LastName,
       Customers.firstname
FROM   Customers
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   Purchases
               WHERE  Purchases.customers_id = Customers.id
                      AND Month(purchasedate) = 2)
```

Considering you want to pull customer information who purchased in `2` month of any year

Comment: You have select Customers.id and @cars10 has select id, without the customer prefix.  Is there a difference between these?

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut - zero difference

Answer (score 1):

Your query will return a list with duplicates name. Just add `DISTINCT`

Dont use `*`, just include the fields your require.

Also include the `id`, just in case two ppl has same first and last name

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.id, Customers.LastName, Customers.firstname 
from Purchases
inner join Customers
  on Purchases.customers_id = Customers.id
WHERE MONTH(purchasedate) = 2
```

In case you want only the current month sales. you need specify your RDBMS because date function are different.

For example in postgres sql you can use 
[Get first date of month in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069275/get-first-date-of-month-in-postgres)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.id, Customers.LastName, Customers.firstname 
from Purchases
inner join Customers
  on Purchases.customers_id = Customers.id
WHERE date_trunc('month', current_date) = date_trunc('month', purchasedate)
```