# Query Interval Date Postgres Change If Month End

Tags: postgresql

Please if any one can help. My query right now is about to get data between yesterday and 15 day before:

```
SELECT 
 datex, 
 hourx, 
'AX' AS apps, 
 hostname, 
 MAX (max_cpu) AS maxofmax_cpu, 
 MAX (avg_cpu) AS maxofavg_cpu, 
 AVG (max_cpu) AS avgofmax_cpu, 
 AVG (avg_cpu) AS avgofavg_cpu 
FROM 
  tb_example 
WHERE 
  TYPE = 'Active' 
  AND apps = 'AX' 
  AND datex between NOW() - INTERVAL '14 DAY' 
  and NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY' 
GROUP BY 
  1, 
  2, 
  3, 
  4 
ORDER BY 
  1, 
  2
```

Query above is success, i need help how to run query every day to get data last 2 month. Every day query running, It's always running from first date of first month, if the last date of the 2 month change to new month, the first date from the first month also change to first date of second month :

Example :

1. Day one running   : FROM '2021-07-01' TO '2021-09-28'
2. Day two running   : FROM '2021-07-01' TO '2021-09-29'
3. Day three running : FROM '2021-07-01' TO '2021-09-30'
4. Day four running  : FROM '2021-08-01' TO '2021-10-01'
5. Day five running  : FROM '2021-08-01' TO '2021-10-02'

Any help and suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18069328/13808319

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. It works with this query

datex BETWEEN date_trunc('month',current_date) - INTERVAL '3' MONTH AND now()::date - 1